# Books on Numerical Methods for Partial Differential Equations

Tags: differential-equations, textbook-recommendation, na.numerical-analysis

Any good references for undergraduates?

Answer (score 2):

I like this book:

http://books.google.se/books/about/Partial_Differential_Equations_with_Nume.html?id=vZGCaLoEqwgC&redir_esc=y